# Dropdown button on a href menu bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a menu bar consisting of multiple links and I wanted to have link number three a dropdown list.

Is there a way that I can possibly put a dropdown list under these a href links? I need to have tab three to have a dropdown list with values six and seven. I cannot find any other examples on the internet. Please help

```css
nav {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #34495e;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 0;
}

nav a {
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav .animation {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease 0s;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

a:nth-child(1) {
  width: 200px;
}

a:nth-child(2) {
  width: 200px;
}

a:nth-child(3) {
  width: 200px;
}

a:nth-child(4) {
  width: 200px;
}

a:nth-child(5) {
  width: 200px;
}

nav a:nth-child(1):hover~.animation {
  width: 200px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #29363B;
}

nav a:nth-child(2):hover~.animation {
  width: 200px;
  left: 200px;
  background-color: #EA495F;
}

nav a:nth-child(3):hover~.animation {
  width: 200px;
  left: 400px;
  background-color: #F4837D;
}

nav a:nth-child(4):hover~.animation {
  width: 200px;
  left: 600px;
  background-color: #FAA664;
}

nav a:nth-child(5):hover~.animation {
  width: 200px;
  left: 800px;
  background-color: #99B998;
}

.active {
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #29363B;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#" class="active" style="text-decoration: none; color: white">ONE</a>
  <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: white">TWO</a>
  <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: white">THREE</a>
  <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: white">FOUR</a>
  <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: white">FIVE</a>
  <div class="animation start-home"></div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown_navbar.asp ?

Comment: @sidarcy yes but the problem is I have no div, and whenever I added one, the code messes up

Answer (score 0):

You can have a select inside a link, which is hidden, until that link is hovered over.

```
link__dropdown {
    display: none;
}

link:hover link__dropdown {
    display: block;
}


<nav>
  <a href="#" class="active" style="text-decoration: none; color: white">ONE</a>
  <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: white" class="link">TWO</a>
  <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: white" class="link">
      <select class="link__dropdown">
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
      </select>
  </a>
  <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: white" class="link">FOUR</a>
  <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: white" class="link">FIVE</a>
  <div class="animation start-home"></div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Is there a way that the select will be in text form?

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand the question, but you can in theory have any inline element inside the anchor tag, so you could have a list or a dropdown, or just some anchor tags

Answer (score 0):

One Way is to use pure CSS and show the Dropdown each time a user hovers on a list item containing a link as follows.

The HTML and CSS:

```css
.navigation__item {

    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2rem 2rem;
    text-transform: capitalize;

    position: relative;
}

/* links */
.navigation__item a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

/* secondary ul */
.navigation__item ul {
    display: none;
}

/* li:hover */
.navigation__item:hover {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
}


/* secondary ul visibility change */
.navigation__item:hover ul {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 2000;
    display: block;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-top: 1rem;

    width: 20rem;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -10%);

    position: absolute;
}
/* secondary li */
.navigation__item:hover ul li {
    display: block;
    padding: 1rem 1rem;
}

/* hover effect on dropdown links */
.navigation__item:hover ul li:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
}


/* Change sytling for first list item */
.navigation__item:hover ul li:first-of-type {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navigation__list">
    <li class="navigation__item active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="navigation__item">Services&#x25BC;
        <ul>
            <li><a>View All Services</a></li>
            <li>Service 1 </li>
            <li>Service 2</li>
            <li>Service 3 </li>
            <li>Service 4 </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navigation__item">Blog&#x25BC;
        <ul>
            <li><a href="blog">Browse Our Blog</a></li>
            <li>Something else</li>
            <li>Something else</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navigation__item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```